# Does the existence of a "strong name assignment" should ensure that the assembly is stored in GAC?

Tags: .net, assemblies, clr, gac, assembly-signing

If I say, 'The existence of a "strong name assignment" ensures that the assembly is stored in GAC' would I be correct in terms of best-practices?

If I rephares it differently: No strong name should be assigned to an assembly in case it won't be shared globally, would it be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To install an assembly in the GAC, you must give the assembly a strong name.

[(Source)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808)

However there are also other reasons to use strong names. Strong names allows you to be sure that you are loading the assembly that you want to load, and that it hasn't been modified. This can be useful whether or not you wish to put the assembly in the GAC.

So, no... having a strong name does not "ensure that the assembly is stored in the GAC".